# Is it possible to control how you enter an island?

Tags: tiny-wings

When entering a new island, it seems that the bird is flying at different altitudes. Especially on one of the later islands, it is sometimes possible to perfectly enter a slope, while other times, it seems impossible for the same island.

Is it possible to somehow control this, or is it totally random?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the islands are all set. There's a pattern, and no random stuffs. Although it seems that the bird is flying in different altitudes, it's actually the same.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I know they change every day. But on the same day, on one of the later islands, I sometimes seem to enter at an altitude where it is possible to actually hit a slope. Other times not.

Comment: Well they DO change everyday but it's all set.

Comment: I just tested by flying to the second island at different speed. Sometimes the bird touches the clouds, sometimes it does not. This indicates different altitudes.

Comment: Hmm... Why I got this answer because I always fly at the same altitudes. No matter how fast/slow I am, I always touch slopes perfectly.

Comment: @Magnilex A fairly substantial aspect of the game is is how *you control* the bird to gain momentum on the hills and thereby gain altitude between touchdowns.  Surely you must have noticed this when going from hill to hill on a single island.  Why would you think the jump to a new island behaves any differently?